# Getting vue devServer proxy to work with different local ports in docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, proxy

Going a little crazy here trying to get this set up properly.  I have Vue running with devServer in docker, and then a separate volume running json-server, for serving up fake api data.  For starters, I'd be happy to get this simple example working, but I keep getting proxy errors.  Here is my current configs.

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  front:
    container_name: front
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

  api:
    image: vimagick/json-server
    command: -H 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -w db.json
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./server/data:/data
```

Dockerfile:

```rb
FROM node:lts-alpine as front

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Add necessary files to app
ENV PATH ./:/app/:./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV=development

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package.lock.json

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install --silent

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)

COPY ./ .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

All of the above works fine.  Everything above builds, and they are both running on their respective ports.

I can navigate to `http://localhost:3000/posts`, and I see the fake json I'm expecting.  And I can do hot module reloading, dev, etc. on `http://localhost:8080/`.  Now here's the rub.  I want to use data from the json server in the vue app, and I want to proxy my requests from `http://localhost:8080/api/*` to `http://localhost:3000/$1`.  Here is my Vue.Config file:

```js
module.exports={
  devServer: {
      proxy: {
        "^/api/": {
          target: "http://localhost:3000/",
          secure: false,
          pathRewrite: {
            "/api/*": "/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Then within the app, I make requests like `axios.get('/api/posts/')`.  I've tried about 100 different subtle variations of the code above in all three files, but every time I get this error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /posts from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:3000/ (**ECONNREFUSED**).

I'm thinking that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work, because I've followed every instruction and copied and pasted from Vue's instructions.  Any insight that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So are you running this in docker-compose all the time - meaning the ECONNREFUSED error - does it come when you are running the compose file above?

Comment: @taleodor - If I understand your question correctly, the syntax I use to start docker is, `docker-compose up`.  Anytime I've made changes to anything other than vue components or other hmr items, I've stopped and restarted docker using docker-compose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here that proxy to `localhost` is incorrect. It should work if you change your vue config to the following:

```
module.exports={
  devServer: {
      proxy: {
        "^/api/": {
          target: "http://api:3000",
          secure: false,
          pathRewrite: {
            "/api/*": "/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Basically, the change is replacing host from `localhost` to `api`. Reason for that is that docker-compose resolves host by service names. And since your service name is `api`, host should also be `api`.

To clarify a little more, the host here is not from your machine's prospective but from the vue.js container prospective. And from the vue.js container prospective, api is a separate host (not a localhost anymore). Hope this makes sense - if more clarification is needed, lmk.

Comment: Sweet.  That was it.. It worked straight away.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Your answer was a life saver. I would have never figured this out. Thank you!

Comment: I am not using docker but simply having a dev server running locally on port 8081. And the vue web app is running on another port. I am getting the same error. My vue.config.js is in the same form as the original post. Don't think in my case I shall replace `localhost` with `api`. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @stt106 Your issue does not seem to be related. Feel free to create a separate SO or find me on DevOps Discord - might be able to help you there - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ

Comment: @taleodor Thanks for the reply. I have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149840/vue-local-dev-server-proxy-configuration and would appreciate if you can take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, but my docker-compose configuration exposes port 80, so a little attention at this point, I spent 3 days looking and redoing the configuration and the exposed port lacked attention.
ports:
       - "8000:80"

my proxy config is: target: 'http://webserver:80/'
NOT :8000